# What does a function n-mod(a,m) such as 8-mod(330,8) do on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-compression

I really can't figure out what it does.

More specifically, I am working on image compression on Matlab and I am provided a code that looks like this:

```
X=imread('image1.jpg');

s=size(X);      % image1.jpg has size 330 x 220
offset1 = mod(8-mod(s(1),8),8);
offset2 = mod(8-mod(s(2),8),8);
if offset1 ~= 0 || offset2 ~= 0
  X(s(1)+offset1, s(2)+offset2, 3) = 0;
end

figure(1)
image(X);
axis image
axis off
```

Trying to figure out what that if statement does, but I have no clue what that offset1 and offset2 is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

They're trying to determine whether the image size is a multiple of 8.  JPEG images are always multiples of 8 in size *internally* because they are made from 8x8 DCT blocks.  The header can specify a smaller size, in which case only the specified upper-leftmost portion is visible, and the right and bottom are trimmed.

The part `8 - mod(s(1), 8)` is computing how many more bytes it would take to get to the next multiple of 8 in the X size.  The outer `mod(..., 8)` just folds the case of "8 more bytes" back into "0 more bytes".

Comment: I still don't get what 8-mod(a,m) does mathematically.. Can you please explain how it is calculated mathematically for this part?

Comment: @WillSon:  The modulo operation is the integer remainder of `a / m`.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: Of course I know what regular modular(i.e remainder) does. But what does that prefix, namely "8-" part of the 8-mod actually do?

Comment: `m - mod(a,m)` tells you what you'd have to add to `a` such that `mod(a,m)==0`

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. But, in general, what if the prefix does not equal to m? such as 3-mod(31,4)?

Comment: @WillSon Are you asking how subtraction works?  Why do you think this is more special than `3 - sin(31)`?